Mypaint crashes in Kubuntu 24.04; how to fix?
I installed mypaint with sudo apt install mypaint. However, it crashes whenever as soon as I click on the drawing area.
How to fix it?
Here is the terminal output. Segmengtation fault occurs as soon as I try to draw.
$ mypaint
INFO: mypaint: Installation layout: conventional POSIX-like structure with prefix '/usr'
INFO: gui.main: No locale setting found, using system locale
INFO: lib.i18n: POSIX: LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
INFO: lib.i18n: POSIX: LANGUAGE=''
INFO: lib.i18n: Value of LANGUAGE after cleanup: ''
INFO: gui.compatibility: Setting mode to 2.x (standard)
INFO: gui.compatibility: Setting default layer type to Pigment
INFO: gui.device: New device 'Wayland Pointer' (GDK_SOURCE_MOUSE, axes:2, class=GdkWaylandDevice, vendor=None, product=None)
INFO: gui.device: New device 'Wayland Touch' (GDK_SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN, axes:2, class=GdkWaylandDevice, vendor=None, product=None)
INFO: gui.document: Initialized background from '/usr/share/mypaint/backgrounds/mrmamurk/mamurk_e_1.png'
WARNING: gui.keyboard: Ignoring keybinding for '<Actions>/BrushModifierActions/BlendModeMenu'
INFO: gui.brushmanager: Switching default pigment setting to On
INFO: lib.document: load_ora: '/home/archisman/.local/share/mypaint/scratchpads/autosave.ora'
INFO: lib.document: 0.068s load_ora total
INFO: gui.filehandling: Loaded scratchpad from '/home/archisman/.local/share/mypaint/scratchpads/autosave.ora'
INFO: gui.compatibility: Setting default layer type to Pigment
Segmentation fault


While I have added an workaround (using appimage), feel free to add your answer if you know how to fix.

try running it from the terminal and see what errors get shown when it crashes.

@Esther I have added the terminal output.

An workaround is to download the official mypaint appimage.
cd .local && mkdir bin && cd bin
wget https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/releases/download/v2.0.1/MyPaint-v2.0.1.AppImage

Now mark the appimage as executable.
chmod +x MyPaint-v2.0.1.AppImage

Now, create a symlink to the appimage, so that opening mypaint from menu will open this appimage.
sudo mv /usr/bin/mypaint /usr/bin/mypaint-old
sudo ln -s $HOME/.local/bin/MyPaint-v2.0.1.AppImage /usr/bin/mypaint

Enjoy using mypaint!


Due to the link the appimage will be overwritten if you recieve an upgrade for the mypaint deb package. This may happen without you noticing (unattended upgrades). Not dangerous at all but something to keep in mind.

I know. However, creating a symlink in .local/bin may require additional steps (adding that to path) in some Ubuntu installations. So I went for usr/bin. It is unlikely that mypaint will receive an update given Ubuntu does not update most of the software in the repositories.

Take a look at ~/.profile, ~/.local/bin should be added to PATH if the folder exits. A relogin might be necessary.

@mook765 I know that, but on some Ubuntu flavors (I am unsure which) it is not in PATH by default. I just went for /usr/bin to shorten the answer.
